# cronjob not running on Ubuntu server, same scripts under cron work on Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've recently configured a new Ubuntu 22.04 server for a project I'm working on, which replaces a Debian 7 server which I initially used. The project runs mostly PHP scripts that are run at specific times (or all the time) based on what is provided on the cron.

I've noticed though that while the crons are the same as what were used on the Debian server, some aren't running at all (as the scripts generate a slack message when they run). When I run the scripts myself (using the same path as I have in the cron) they run without issue.

This is an example of the cron that I'm running, which should run at midnight and at 3am every day.

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/html/project/cmd/src/futureResults.php
0 3 * * * php /var/www/html/project/cmd/src/updateResults.php
```

When I edit the cron as well, I enter `crontab -e` - I don't run it with `sudo` as the scripts themselves don't need to run with any elevated permissions.

I have also looked in `/var/log` and I don't seem to have a `syslog` file. I have a `php8.1-fpm.log` file which isn't updated around the time these crons run, and none of the other log files I can see are updated at the time these crons run to indicate an error.

So I'm a little lost, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Redirect the output of this script to log to see what is the problem. And do not forget to add absolute path to `php`!

Comment: under which user does the php script runs? I would suggest to use on top either "SHELL=/bin/bash" or with all loaded stuff "SHELL=/bin/bash -l" (it's a lowercase L) to force bash as shell, some scripts have issues with sh

Comment: I have fiddled with this issue since asking it, and it's currently working. changing the permissions on the files being executed using `chmod +x` as well as using the full path for PHP seems to have done the trick!